# Get tensorflow serving response directly in output proto format

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0

I have an output vector coming from tensorflow model which is a 50x1 vector of probabilities [0.4 0.3 0.4 ...    0.5] where first 20 dimensions are user vectors and last 30 are item vectors each with a particular proto value. Is there a way to directly export proto values from within tensorflow as part of tfserving
For example

```
enum User {
    Feature1 = 0;
    // Geo
    Feature2 = 1101;
    Feature3 = 1102;
   
    Feature20}

enum Item{
   Feature1 = 0
    

   Feature30 = 2103
}
message UserProb {
User user = 1;
float confidence = 2;
```

}

```
      message ItemProb {
    Item user = 1;
    float confidence = 2;
}
```

Comment: Why not use tensorflow serving http api ?

Comment: Because this is a GRPC call that needs to be used by some other client